# How to get values of city and state from response of http call on event of filling in pin code in angular 6

Tags: events, event-handling, angular6, angular-httpclient

Working on populating the values of city and state via entering the pincode, i have written this code that works at times, and not always.
Issue - every time i enter a number the http service is called, so until i enter the whole 6 digit number it would have called the http 6 times, and for the 5th digit itself it populates the value of state and city.
Also giving an error telling the response returned is undefined though the fields are populated

component.ts

```
 ngOnInit(): void {

        this.policyService.getPolicyInfo().subscribe(response => {
                    this.vehicleDetailsForm.patchValue( {'field':null} )
              })
}
onSubmitPin() {
        let formValuePin: any = {
            pincode: this.proposalDetailsForm.value.p_pin,


        }
        console.log(this.proposalDetailsForm.value.p_pin)
        this.policyService.getPinCode(formValuePin)
            .pipe()
            .subscribe(vehpin => {
                this.displayVehPin(vehpin),
                    console.log('vehpin: ', vehpin); //
                (error: any) => this.errorMessage = <any>error
            }
            )
    }

    displayVehPin(vehpin): void {
        this.vehidv = vehpin;
        console.log('vehpin: ', vehpin); //
        if (this.proposalDetailsForm) {
            console.log("you almost der...")
        }
        // the data on the form
        this.proposalDetailsForm.patchValue({
            p_state: vehpin.data.state_name,
            p_city: vehpin.data.city_name,

        });
        console.log(vehpin)
    }
```

HTML code

```
<div class="col-lg-4 m-form__group-sub">
                                            <mat-form-field class="example-full-width" appearance="outline">
                                                <mat-label>Pin Code</mat-label>
                     <input matInput placeholder="" formControlName="p_pin" (onChanges)="onSubmitPin()">

</mat-form-field>
                                            <label *ngIf="proposalDetailsForm.get('p_pin').errors?.required"  class="invalid-feedback">
            This Field is required.
            </label>
                        <label *ngIf="proposalDetailsForm.controls.p_pin.errors?.pattern"  class="invalid-feedback">
                                                        Should be a valid 6 digit number.
                                                    </label>
                                        </div>
```

Comment: Probably on the onchanges, but not so sure yet. I don’t use angular, but the logic between your issue and that seems like a correlation. Maybe it should be onsubmit? Doesn’t seem like you really want to do an event on every change.

Comment: @Jesse thanks but onsubmit doesn't seem to work as well